# Get the Domain that an Ajax Request is coming from

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, jsonp, jersey

I have a set of JSONP Web Service created on my J2EE application, which will be used by a website under a different domain. The web services have been created using the Jersey framework.

What I want to know is, is there a way I can tell in my Web Service code, what domain the request came from?  What I'm hoping is that there is a value in the HttpHeader which would have this value.

Also would it be possible for the user making the Ajax call, to fake this value, or to put in another value before they send the call?

What I'm hoping to use this for is to restrict the domains that can call my web service.  I need to use JSONP, but i don't want my web service to be available to anybody who reverse engineers my JavaScript code.

Or does anybody know another way of doing this?

Comment: Would the HTTP referer not have this information?

Comment: Yes that might be what I'm looking for.  Could that value be faked?  As in could you send an Ajax request and overwrite that value with name of my domain

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP_REFERER as already mentioned

Some code example:
talker.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTTP Referer example</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'observer.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.result').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

observer.php

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

The result looks like this:

```
http://localhost/talker.php
```

Comment: Java was asked for, not PHP

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to authenticate the users on the distant domain which is supposed to send the request. So for example the server on the distant domain could emit some encrypted value to authenticated users. Then when sending the JSONP request you would send this token to the web service which would decrypt it. The idea is that both servers should share some common secret to encrypt/decrypt this token. This way you can ensure that the request came from the other server.

Comment: Surely that would just make it harder to reverse engineer, but not impossible?  If somebody else took all the JavaScript code, which they can do, they could include it all on their site and then have the authenticated values included.

Comment: @user574040, yes but the value of the token will be generated by the server. And the server would emit this token only to authenticated users on this site. So without the server the javascript is useless.

Comment: But how would you authenticate the uses, before you send them the token?

Comment: @user574040, ask them for username/password.

Comment: Asking the user using the site for a username/password is not an option, I want the use of the Ajax to be hidden from the users.

Answer (score 0):

Your RESTful services are hosted on a web server and with REST you're limited to the standard stuff that comes as part of HTTP. For example, you could get the host IP that sent the request, but be aware that this can be spoofed.

One option open to you would be to require the web service requests to be digitally signed. This basically means that the caller creates and adds a [Message Authentication Code](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html) to the request. The MAC is generated using a secret key that only an authorised user of your service knows. You can (and should) also add a user ID to the web service request, allowing you to give each user their own secret key.

Remember that if your services are being called by javascript (eg using AJAX) then the calls will come from the client computer. This means they are completely open to reverse engineering. If you rely on javascript to digitally sign the request then the javascript would need to know the secret key, therefore exposing it to any attacker.

Comment: So if I use values that come as part of HTTP, i could tell that they are coming from the correct source.  But people can spoof or fake these values, but setting them manually before they make a request.  If i just had this check on though, people who reverse engineered the code might not be able to figure out what check i'm doing on the server.  I'm wary about using something like MAC, because i'm fairly sure the first thing that will happen when i expose this is that it will be reverse engineered.